# how to draw multi-day event rectangles across multiple days on a month-view calendar on IOS?

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, calendar, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

What approach is recommended to draw multi-day event rectangles across multiple days on a month-view calendar on IOS?  Keeping in mind the goal to be able to drag/drop the event bars around on the calendar

Two options that come to mind, however I'm not sure which would be best (or if there is another) is:

1. Use `UICollectionView` (with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`) - but then there wouldn't be one object per multi-day event would there?  i.e. Every multiple day event would need to effectively draw a portion of itself separately in each day cell, and ensure the drawing lines up to appear as single bar
2. Draw the calendar yourself, so you can put multi-day rectangle bars for ease in drag-droppping, but then you wouldn't get the rendering support from the `UICollectionView` associated with continuing to scroll through the calendar and it creating/removing cells as required?

Any suggestions/direciton welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

- create your own collectionviewcell representing a day (you might probably
  already do this).
- add an 'events' property to the cell holding
  all events which start, end or include the day (you set this in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`).
- you have to decide if you draw the rectangle by yourself (overriding drawRect) or if you
  add a view (eg. imageView, ...). In any case: There are
  4 scenarios:

  1. The event starts in the cell but ends in another cell
  2. The event starts in the cell and ends in the cell
  3. The event starts in another cell and ends in this cell
  4. The event starts before the cell and ends after the cell

For each of this scenarios, draw the corresponding graphics or add the corresponding view. If you use a plain colored rectangle / view, this ist very easy, if the rectangle has a border or round corners, you have to draw different rectangles for each scenario.

If you drag the event, just adjust the dates of the event and be sure it is removed / added from / to the corresponding cells and repaint the cells.

An alternative (probably easier) way to the 'events' property might be, that the cell can inquire the corresponding events from somthing like an event manager.

Comment: thanks - can I ask (a) would the concept be to trigger an entire reload after the drag, or perhaps find a way to invalidate all cells between the start and end dates that were involved?, and (b) what about during drag and somehow showing the user a view/indication of the item being dragged?   Ideally (might be hard) it would be like iMovie where as you drag it it highlights the location of the closest available it might drop at that point in time.

Comment: You do not need to reload the whole collectionView. Since you know the start and end date (which change while you drag), you can figure out which cells need to be updated and you can update them with reloadItemsAtIndexPaths. Since you adjust the start and end date while dragging, the rectangle should be moved automatically. You could also draw a different rectangle while dragging. For the closest destination i would insert a temporary event which is rendered the same way (you should get this for free).

Comment: You may add a property 'dragging' and a property 'placeholder' to the event class. Then you can decide which kind of rectangle you have to draw inside the cell.